# How can I make a "FOR"(loop) in html, using chameleon and pyramid in python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid, chameleon, template-tal

How can a make a loop using chameleon and pyramid in my html?
I search but  i found nothing like that =/
Is easier use javascript in this case?
I use datatable in MACADMIN(bootstrap theme).

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="data-table" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Rendering engine
        </th>
        <th>
          Browser
        </th>
        <th>
          Platform(s)
        </th>
        <th>
          Engine version
        </th>
        <th>
          CSS grade
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         Maybe put FOR here? like {for x items in "TABLE"}
      <tr>
        <td>
          {orgao_doc[x].nome}
        </td>
        <td>
          {orgao_doc[x].cargo}
        </td>
        <td>
          {orgao_doc[x].coleta}
        </td>
        <td>
          {orgao_doc[x].email}
        </td>
        <td>
          {orgao_doc[x].endereco}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="clearfix">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`tal:repeat` attribute](https://chameleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#tal-repeat) to repeat parts of a template, given a sequence:

```html
<tbody>
  <tr tal:repeat="item orgao_doc">
    <td>${item.nome}</td>
    <td>${item.cargo}</td>
    <td>${item.coleta}</td>
    <td>${item.email}</td>
    <td>${item.endereco}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The `<tr>` tag is repeatedly inserted into the output, once for each element in `orgao_doc`. The name `item` is bound to each element when rendering this part of the template.

Comment: I saw "tal" in documentation from chameleon,i didn't understand. thanks, it's work fine, but i need to put $ before {item.nome} like <td>${item.nome}</td>